# state are being updated before reducer is update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm using userReducer to manage user state across the app but while updating the state using reducer the state is updates before reducer is able to update it.

[Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJmlk.png)

here you can see that the previous state variable is updated to new value in payload.

store.js

```
import { compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from "redux";


import { logger } from "redux-logger";
import { rootReducer } from "./rootReducer";


export const store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(logger));
```

rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { postReducer } from "./posts/posts.reducer";
import { userReducer } from "./user/user.reducer";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  post: postReducer,
  user:userReducer
});
```

userReducer

```
import { User_Action_Types } from "./user.types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  data: {
  _id: "",
  name: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
},
};

export const userReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  console.log({ action, state });
  switch (type) {
    case User_Action_Types.SetUser: {
      state.data = payload;
      return state;
    }
    case User_Action_Types.ResetUser: {
      return INITIAL_STATE;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I tried to change actions then reinstalled the modules but nothing worked.
Please help to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

current your mutating state return new state in reducer

```
case User_Action_Types.SetUser: {
      
      return {
             ...state,
             data: payload
      };
    }
```

Comment: There's no need to iterate the `payload` property by [spreading (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it into a new object. This looks good otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it is not solving the issue. Main problem is the state in reducer is changing before reducer is called you can see inspect that the prev state of the reducer includes the data in payload which prevent the rerendering of component which is dependent on the state change.

Comment: Can you share code sandbox link with this problem